# the relation between add key/value and mapassign method in go1.10.3

Tags: dictionary, go

I am reading the source code of map in [go1.10.3](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/map.go).It seemed there exist corresponding method about operation such as:

```
 makemap(t *maptype, hint int, h *hmap) *hmap ==> m = make(map[xx]yy)
 mapaccess1(t *maptype, h *hmap, key unsafe.Pointer)==> m['key']
```

but I cant find the correspond method for the operation which add key/value as below:

```
 m['xx']='yy'
```

there exist a method called mapassign which has some similarity with this 
operation.

```
 mapassign(t *maptype, h *hmap, key unsafe.Pointer) unsafe.Pointer
```

this will add a new key to the map, but as we can see, **the input arguments has no value**. And another question is when it has already this key, it maybe update this key.

```
        if !alg.equal(key, k) {
            continue
        }
        // already have a mapping for key. Update it.
        if t.needkeyupdate {//why??
            typedmemmove(t.key, k, key)
        }
```

since the two key is equal, why should update it?

**summary:** 
1. the relation between add key/value operation and method *mapassign*?
2. why it maybe need to update the key since the insert key and the key which has already exist is equal in mapassign method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the operation `m[k] = v`, the caller copies the value `v` to the address returned by `mapassign`.
2. The comments in the function [needkeyupdate](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6fe8ee78e9b4870ebc1de2b5cfd6170a78a56c00/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/reflect.go#L1070-L1096) explain why some types need key updates: floating point & complex -0 and 0 are equal, but different values; string might have smaller backing store.